# NDK-build causes error

Tags: android, android-ndk

I had been trying to solve this issue for quiet a long time,I am using a library called FreeImage and when tries to do the NDK build the code results in following error
My source can be downloaded from

copy.html">http://www.4shared.com/zip/1C3vpLI7/android-imagefilter-ndk_*copy*.html
Thanking you in advance for your valuable efforts-

```
tribute.cpp+0x8): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::Init()'
ImfChromaticitiesAttribute.cpp:(.text.startup._GLOBAL__sub_I_ImfChromaticitiesAttribute.cpp+0x24): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::~Init()'
/home/flock/ANDROID/android-ndk-r8/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.4.3/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: Dwarf Error: mangled line number section.
./obj/local/armeabi/libfreeimage.a(ImfCompressionAttribute.o): In function `_GLOBAL__sub_I_ImfCompressionAttribute.cpp':
ImfCompressionAttribute.cpp:(.text.startup._GLOBAL__sub_I_ImfCompressionAttribute.cpp+0x8): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::Init()'
ImfCompressionAttribute.cpp:(.text.startup._GLOBAL__sub_I_ImfCompressionAttribute.cpp+0x24): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::~Init()'
./obj/local/armeabi/libfreeimage.a(ImfCompressor.o): In function `Imf::newCompressor(Imf::Compression, unsigned int, Imf::Header const&)':
ImfCompressor.cpp:(.text._ZN3Imf13newCompressorENS_11CompressionEjRKNS_6HeaderE+0x10): undefined reference to `__gnu_thumb1_case_uqi'
ImfCompressor.cpp:(.text._ZN3Imf13newCompressorENS_11CompressionEjRKNS_6HeaderE+0xb8): undefined reference to `__cxa_end_cleanup'
./obj/local/armeabi/libfreeimage.a(ImfCompressor.o):(.ARM.extab.text._ZN3Imf13newCompressorENS_11CompressionEjRKNS_6HeaderE+0x0): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'
./obj/local/armeabi/libfreeimage.a(ImfCompressor.o): In function `Imf::newTileCompressor(Imf::Compression, unsigned int, unsigned int, Imf::Header const&)':
ImfCompressor.cpp:(.text._ZN3Imf17newTileCompressorENS_11CompressionEjjRKNS_6HeaderE+0x12): undefined reference to `__gnu_thumb1_case_uqi'
ImfCompressor.cpp:(.text._ZN3Imf17newTileCompressorENS_11CompressionEjjRKNS_6HeaderE+0x64): undefined reference to `__cxa_allocate_exception'
ImfCompressor.cpp:(.text._ZN3Imf17newTileCompressorENS_11CompressionEjjRKNS_6HeaderE+0x8a): undefined reference to `__cxa_throw'
ImfCompressor.cpp:(.text._ZN3Imf17newTileCompressorENS_11CompressionEjjRKNS_6HeaderE+0xe4): undefined reference to `__cxa_end_cleanup'
./obj/local/armeabi/libfreeimage.a(ImfCompressor.o):(.ARM.extab.text._ZN3Imf17newTileCompressorENS_11CompressionEjjRKNS_6HeaderE+0x0): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'
./obj/local/armeabi/libfreeimage.a(ImfCompressor.o): In function `_GLOBAL__sub_I_ImfCompressor.cpp':
ImfCompressor.cpp:(.text.startup._GLOBAL__sub_I_ImfCompressor.cpp+0x8): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::Init()'
ImfCompressor.cpp:(.text.startup._GLOBAL__sub_I_ImfCompressor.cpp+0x24): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::~Init()'
./obj/local/armeabi/libfreeimage.a(ImfCompressor.o):(.data.rel.ro+0x0): undefined reference to `vtable for __cxxabiv1::__class_type_info'
/home/flock/ANDROID/android-ndk-r8/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.4.3/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: Dwarf Error: mangled line number section.
./obj/local/armeabi/libfreeimage.a(ImfConvert.o): In function `_GLOBAL__sub_I_ImfConvert.cpp':
ImfConvert.cpp:(.text.startup._GLOBAL__sub_I_ImfConvert.cpp+0x8): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::Init()'
ImfConvert.cpp:(.text.startup._GLOBAL__sub_I_ImfConvert.cpp+0x24): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::~Init()'
/home/flock/ANDROID/android-ndk-r8/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.4.3/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: Dwarf Error: mangled line number section.
./obj/local/armeabi/libfreeimage.a(ImfDoubleAttribute.o): In function `_GLOBAL__sub_I_ImfDoubleAttribute.cpp':
ImfDoubleAttribute.cpp:(.text.startup._GLOBAL__sub_I_ImfDoubleAttribute.cpp+0x8): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::Init()'
ImfDoubleAttribute.cpp:(.text.startup._GLOBAL__sub_I_ImfDoubleAttribute.cpp+0x24): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::~Init()'
/home/flock/ANDROID/android-ndk-r8/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.4.3/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: Dwarf Error: mangled line number section.
./obj/local/armeabi/libfreeimage.a(ImfEnvmapAttribute.o): In function `_GLOBAL__sub_I_ImfEnvmapAttribute.cpp':
ImfEnvmapAttribute.cpp:(.text.startup._GLOBAL__sub_I_ImfEnvmapAttribute.cpp+0x8): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::Init()'
ImfEnvmapAttribute.cpp:(.text.startup._GLOBAL__sub_I_ImfEnvmapAttribute.cpp+0x24): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::~Init()'
```

My Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE:= freeimage
LOCAL_SRC_FILES :=libfreeimage.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE:= imageprocessing
LOCAL_SRC_FILES:= imageprocessing.c
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES = freeimage
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := freeimage.h
LOCAL_LDLIBS:= -lm -llog -ljnigraphics 
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

My application.mk

```
APP_OPTIM := release
APP_PLATFORM := android-8
APP_STL := gnustl_static
APP_CPPFLAGS += -frtti 
APP_CPPFLAGS += -fexceptions
APP_CPPFLAGS += -DANDROID
APP_ABI:= armeabi
```

Comment: What do your Android.mk and Application.mk files look like?

Comment: Looks like libfreeimage.a had been compiled incorrectly. Try to compile it exactly with same Android NDK you are compiling. Or better - dontuse static library. include the Android.ml makefile of FreeImage, and compile together with your code - it will guarantee that you won't have this kind of problem.

Comment: What ABI are you building for? I see undefined references that indicate that some of the code was built for ARM, but you seem to be using an x86 toolchain.

Comment: @Martins Mozeiko...Hi I had been using a downloaded version of libfreeimage.a...How can I make my code to work?

Comment: @Michael...I havent been able to understand the significance of the ABI yet...please help me with respect to this... And I just want to make sure that the code works pretty fast and almost in all devices..

Comment: Well, simply put, one part of your code appears to be built for ARM (probably the Freeimage lib that you downloaded), and you're trying to link it against the rest of your code which you're building for x86. This obviously won't work. You need to either find a prebuilt version of Freeimage.a for x86, or build it yourself from its source code.

Comment: Well Is it not possible for me to make the rest of my code too for ARM?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are seeing a bug in gcc/NDK that manifests itself slightly differently on Linux, Cygwin, and Windows (non Cygwin).

Here's what I did to fix it (works for Linux and for one of my developers who is blind and has to use Cygwin)...

- Remove the line that says, `APP_STL := gnustl_static` from your Application.mk (it's broken in the NDK; moreover, it's broken slightly differently on Linux Cygwin, Windows)

- add three lines to Andriod.mk that say,
`LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(NDK_ROOT)/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.6/include`
`LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(NDK_ROOT)/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.6/libs/armeabi-v7a/include`
`$(LOCAL_LDLIBS) += $(NDK_ROOT)/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.6/libs/armeabi-v7a/libgnustl_static.a`

   ^^^This line must be near the end of your $(LOCAL_LDLIBS)

The forgoing will accomplish what having, "APP_STL := gnustl_static" in your Application.mk was supposed to.